# How to parse a CSV file downloaded from Firebase Storage Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm creating an application to manage an entry in an event by using Swift 3. I'm using Firebase to store CSV files of my client. These CSV files represents a database of all participants to an event.

*Example of rows in my CSV file stored in Firebase Storage :*

```
id;event;lastname;firstname;phone;email;address;zipcode;city;added_in_event;comment;checked;checked_date;created;created_uid
479;NULL;CHARLANES;Herve;Google;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;1;24/11/2016 11:43;NULL;NULL
480;NULL;CHARLANES;Eve;Google;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;NULL;1;24/11/2016 13:21;NULL;NULL[...]
```

Firebase website gives you tutorials to understand how to use Firebase Storage to store an image and how to download this image from our app. It's quite easy, you just have to use your reference `gsReference.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in [...]` and store the result from 'data' of type `NSData` in a `UIImage` and the job is done.

Link to Firebase Tutorials : https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files

But today, I would like to download a CSV file instead of an image. As Firebase tutorials say, the result in 'data' of type `NSData` is my CSV freshly downloaded. I would like to read the content of my file and store all rows into a tab[].
But when I print 'data', the only information that I can have is the right size of the CSV file "1796 bytes" for this example and not my CSV content.

So I'm trying to encode the `NSData` from 'data', but it doesn't work too...

You guys have some tips for me?

**Here is an example of my function :**

```
  func downloadMyCSV(){
        //Firebase Storage Reference
        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
        //location of my CSV file in Firebase Storage Reference
        let gsReference = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://xxxx-xxxx.appspot.com/USERS_BDD_CSV/XXXxq5qur9XQOqAOoAeWH9F5AXo2/Tab-User-Trial.csv")

        //Firebase function for download a file with a reference
        gsReference.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                //Sh*t happen
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print(data)//print : "1796 bytes" the exacte size of my CSV file stored in firebase storage

                if data != nil {//Me trying to encode
                    do {
                        let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                        let s = try String(contentsOf: url!, encoding : .utf8)
                        print("my data : \(dataString)")
                        print(s)
                    }catch let error as NSError{
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post what you get (the value of `dataString`)? 1) this doesn't appear to be a Firebase issue, 2) it's quite possibly a character encoding issue (maybe you're storing values not as UTF8 compatible characters?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking has nothing to do with Firebase actually. You just want to parse `Data`/`NSData` that represent a CSV file. Downloading data from Firebase Storage has nothing to do with it's format since it simply stores raw data.

A CSV file is nothing but comma-separated or semicolon-separated plain text so consider your downloaded data to be a `String`.

**Something to keep in mind here:**

Whatever method you use(d) to upload the CSV file onto Firebase Storage, make sure you use its character encoding later on to decode the downloaded data. This is how you get the `UTF8` data representation of a Swift `String` (in Swift 3)

```
let data = "myCSVString".data(using: .utf8)
```

**Parsing the incoming CSV data:**

As you did in your example, to decode the data back into a string:

```
let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)    // this is only valid if you used UTF8 to encode it
```

and for handling convenience, get an array of all the strings in your CSV like this:

```
let csvStrings = dataString.components(separatedBy: ";")
// this can also be...
let moreGenericCSVStrings = dataString.components(separatedBy: [",", ";"])   // to handle comma separated CSV
```

If you want a less *manual* way of doing this, then there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

**Some CSV Parsers:**

- Objective-C Libraries:

  1. [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser)
  2. [cCSVParse](https://github.com/JanX2/cCSVParse)
- Swift Libraries:

  1. [SwiftCSV](https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV)
  2. [CSwiftV](https://github.com/Daniel1of1/CSwiftV)

Using one of these gives you the advantage of having some helpful methods already in place and the ability to have the content split into more components (rows, headers, etc...) which would require just a bit more work than the example I provided.